# Form value sequence around given values PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a couple of PySpark dataframes, the second of which is derived from the first, checking for anomalies.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "pk": [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3],
    "date": [
        date(2022,4,13), date(2022,4,14), date(2022,4,15), date(2022,4,16),  
        date(2022,4,13), date(2022,4,14), date(2022,4,15), date(2022,4,16),
        date(2022,4,13), date(2022,4,14), date(2022,4,15), date(2022,4,16),
    ],
    "varA": [4, 5, 1, 6, 7, 4, 8, 11, 12, 10, 11, 13],
    "varB": [5, 6, 4, 3, 12, 13, 1, 14, 9, 10, 11, 15],
    "varC": [8, 32, 1, 11, 4, 3, 5, 6, 10, 14, 9, 11]
})

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(df1)
```

So the first data frame is a "wide" data frame. The second is a "long" dataframe, derived from the first as a result of an anomaly processing algorithm. Here, each row is an anomaly.

```
df2 = do_anomaly_processing(df1)

df2.show()

#+-----+-----------+--------+-----+
#|pk   |       date|variable|value|
#+-----+-----------+--------+-----+
#|    1| 2022-04-14|    varA|    5|
#|    2| 2022-04-14|    varA|    4|
#|    3| 2022-04-14|    varA|   10|
#|    3| 2022-04-15|    varC|   14|
#+-----+-----------+--------+-----+
```

The code to produce this dataframe is:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "pk": [1,2,3,3],
    "date": [date(2022,4,14), date(2022,4,14), date(2022,4,14), date(2022,4,15)],
    "variable": ["varA", "varA", "varA", "varC"],
    "value": [5,4,10,14]
})

df2 = spark.createDataFrame(df2)
```

I'd like to create a new dataframe that has the surrounding values for each anomaly listed, which looks like:

```
#+-----+-----------+--------+-----+------+------+
#|pk   |       date|variable|value|v[n-1]|v[n+1]|
#+-----+-----------+--------+-----+------+------+
#|    1| 2022-04-14|    varA|    5|     4|     1|
#|    2| 2022-04-14|    varA|    4|     7|     8|
#|    3| 2022-04-14|    varA|   10|    12|    11|
#|    3| 2022-04-15|    varC|    9|    14|    11|
#+-----+-----------+--------+-----+------+------+
```

In reality, I'd like to be able to put as many past and/or future values in the new dataframe as the data will allow (e.g., `(v[n-5], v[n-4], v[n-3], v[n-2], v[n-1])`, etc -- but always a sequence). I was initially doing this with a `for` loop:

```
for step in dt:
    if step == 0:
        varName = "v[n]"

        shiftedDataframe = melt(
            df1,
            id_vars=["pk", "date"],
            value_vars=["varA", "varB", "varC"],
            var_name=varName
        )
    else:
        if step < 0:
            varName = f"v[n{step}]"
            step = abs(step)
        elif step > 0:
            varName = f"v[n+{step}]"
            step = -step

            shiftedDataframe = melt(
                create_shifted_dataframe(
                    df1,
                    "pk",
                    "date",
                    ["varA", "varB", "varC"],
                    shiftAmount=step
                ),
                id_vars=["pk", "date"],
                value_vars=["varA", "varB", "varC"],
                var_name=varName
            )
    
    df2 = df2.join(df1, on=["pk", "date", "variable"], how="left")
```

NOTE: the functions `melt` and `create_shifted_dataframe` do exactly what you think they do. Effectively, I am creating a shifted version of the original dataframe (`df1`), then forcing it to be a "long" dataframe, and finally, I merge the new shifted-melted version of `df1` into `df2`. This is the best way I could find to do this, but there has to be a more efficient way. I was thinking about doing a pivot, and then a merge but I couldn't figure out how to do this with the different dates in `df2`. Anyhow, I hope this makes sense, and is an interesting problem for someone.

Comment: could you elaborate on how `v[n-1]`, `v[n-2]` is calculated, maybe small equation or some descriptive explanation with samples?   this question seems like XY problem(https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) so let's try to focus on what you try to solve.

Comment: @Emma, the values `v[n-1]` and `v[n-2]` are the values from the day before and two days before for a given `(pk, date, variable)` combination.

Comment: @Emma, I don't believe this is the XY problem. My question has to do with the best way to compute the desired dataframe from the two inputs, `df1` and `df2`. I put a solution to show that I'd attempted to solve the problem rather than just asking a bare question.

Comment: The reason I felt it might be XY is you mentioned anomaly in question and wondered if you want to take an average of n-1, n-2 or diff.  And the wide table like you want to have might not be the best shape to do so I wanted to make sure what you want to do after taking n-1, n-2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the logic, you can leverage `lead` and `lag`.

But first we need to `melt` the `df1` to look like this,

```
+---+----------+--------+--------------+
| pk|      date|variable|original_value|
+---+----------+--------+--------------+
|  1|2022-04-13|    varA|             4|
|  1|2022-04-13|    varB|             5|
...
```

If you have this dataframe, you can join it with `df2`.

```py
df = df1.join(df2, on=['pk', 'date', 'variable'], how='left')
```

Then, you can use `lead` (get value at offset after the current row) and `lag` (get value at offset before the current row) to obtain v[n-1], v[n+1], v[n-2], v[n+2]...

```py
# I will get until n+-2 in this example.
w = Window.partitionBy(['pk', 'variable']).orderBy('date')
df = (df.select('pk', 'date', 'variable', 'value',
        *[F.when(F.col('value').isNotNull(), F.lag('original_value', x).over(w)).alias(f'v[n-{x}]') for x in range(1, 3)],
        *[F.when(F.col('value').isNotNull(), F.lead('original_value', x).over(w)).alias(f'v[n+{x}]') for x in range(1, 3)])
    .filter(F.col('value').isNotNull()))
```

Comment: Excellent solution, thanks!